# Handle multiple python versions and python multiple libraries versions with jupyterhub

Tags: python, jupyterhub

I have a Linux machine that hosts a multiple user Jupyter Hub (TLJH) service.

I started it 1 year ago and today, it is not possible to do any update/upgrade without breaking it.
By update I mean : Linux updates and, but most, Python updates.
For example : I have library loop references. When I install or upgrade a library (1st), it updates another library(2nd) and breaks another (3rd) library

I believe that some thing were baldy configured.

So I'm here to take some testimonials about your potential experiences on this kind of needs.

What I would like to have is :

- A multiple user jupyter environnement
- A way to manage different Python versions and different libraries versions without getting my end users too deep in technique
- Maybe a solution that couples docker and Jupyter. But we need to be able to code in jupyter hub
- Or a way to handle easily one or several kernel per user.
- Any other idea ?

Thank you, let me know if I'm not clear at all or if you are missing informations !

In advance, many thanks guys !

Comment: The way I manage my Python libraries is through [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). They contain their own version of Python and have the ability to hold libraries. This way, you can install or upgrade a library inside a virtual environment and only affect certain code.

Comment: Have you ever linked it to a JupyterHub kernel management ? Should I create one venv per code project then ?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with JupyterHub, but I would says yes, one venv per project.

Comment: @StevensLaurent - MillerTime isn't giving you advice specific to a jupyterhub environment. venv isn't going to work well in this context. You can configure conda to manage multiple environments in a way that is compatible with jupyterhub by keeping your base environment very light - only include what is necessary to support the jupyterhub itself. Then, install all user packages in different environments, making sure `kernelspec` is installed, and making sure the versions of jupyter are pinned to the versions in the base env.

Comment: this will involve rebuilding the user environments from time to time, and this may get messy. there's not a great way around this other than moving to a managed service like colab. one thing we've found helpful is providing multiple docker environment options via a profile_list, but I think that might only be available on the zero2jupyterhub kubernetes version of jupyterhub? not sure how to set up docker with the littlest jupyterhub.

Comment: one way venv could be helpful is if you stop supporting user environments and have them use venv, and you just provide the environment to run jupyterhub. you could always help them set up but it wouldn't be the sole responsibility of the cluster admins. this would probably work better on tljh than z2jh since it's a persistent machine.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelDelgado thanks for the Idea of using condas environments, and I agree with you, even if we are good in configuration in the beginning, in the end, it will become messy. We might try to use the kubernetes version of jupyterhub, which requires another thing to learn, but if we have to, we will.

Comment: Questions to understand : 
-  "stop supporting user environments" means stop supporting python versions of each users ?

Comment: yep that's what I mean. if the users are the ones setting up the environment then you might not have such an acute problem when upgrading jupyterhub - just becomes a problem for a couple users for example, and you can focus on bumping the core jupyter libraries more often. also just fair warning - the kubernetes version is significantly more challenging to setup and maintain than tljh. It offers some very powerful advantages such as the ability to scale to multiple clusters, e.g. extending to [daskhub](https://github.com/dask/helm-chart), but it's no simple config change compared to tljh.

Comment: also - I'd check out the jupyter community forum on [discourse](https://discourse.jupyter.org/c/jupyterhub/tljh/13). you'll probably get more experienced users hanging out over there, and I'm sure there are a few discussions relevant to this topic.